# which one is better? a javascript stored on the root file or the link directly to the js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know what is the difference between the script tags `<script>` well bassically we load our javaScript code inside the script tag and i just found out that we can link a url file inside it.. example `<script src="js/example.js">` this is the common src that i use. and what about the  `<script src="http://example.com/example.js">` well i read in W3C and there are no different and i would like to know which one is faster?(js file loading time....) is it the "js/example.js"(on the root folder) or "http://example.com/example.js" ? 
because when i see the google font.. using google font use less time to load the code.. i hope you guys understand my question :) thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`js/example.js` is 14 bytes. `http://example.com/example.js` is 30 bytes. The difference will be smaller once gzip compression is applied in transport.

The first one will be infinitesimally faster.

---

Loading time should not be a factor in your decision to use an absolute or relative URI.